# Can you make chemical structure diagrams in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, chemfig, chemistry

Can you create diagrams of chemical structures in LaTeX?

Example(s) of "chemical structure diagrams":

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Yes, take a look at the [`chemfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig).

Comment: Here's a way to do it completely online: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238760/simpler-way-to-create-chemical-graphs-using-chemfig

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The answer is: yes. There is actually more than one package to do that:

- [`chemfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig)
- [`ochem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ochem)
- [`streeTeX`](http://ctan.org/pkg/streetex)
- [`XyMTeX`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymtex)
- ConTeXt's [`PPCHTeX`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Chemistry)

I have used all but `XyMTeX` and `PPCHTeX` myself but nowadays only use `chemfig` any more.

`XyMTeX` is in my opinion far from being intuitive so I never bothered learning it. <strike>It also is not regularly updated to CTAN and not part of TeX Live. CTAN has v4.06 but the newest version is v5.00.</strike>

`ochem` nearly offers all one needs but 1) is not available from either major free distribution and 2) the work is done by a Perl script that translates formulae and reaction schemes into PostScript, which means it doesn't work with pdflatex.

`streeTeX` is just too limited in its capabilities besides the fact that it is rather old, is not available from either major free distribution and also doesn't work with pdflatex.

`chemfig` is a rather new and actively maintained package that not only allows to draw skeletal formulae but also has commands for creating whole reaction schemes. It uses [TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for the drawing.

`PPCHTeX` is ConTeXt's chemistry module but it can actually be used with LaTeX, too. I have never used it before and trying to typeset the examples below with it has proven to be more complicated than I thought. That's why I simply copied an example from the [conTeXtgarden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Chemistry).

So if you want to draw your formulas and schemes with LaTeX rather than an external program like `ChemDraw` I can only recommend `chemfig`.

---

A `chemfig` example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{
  HO-[2,.5,2]?<[7,.7](-[2,.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[6,.5]OH)>[1,.7]
    (-[:-65,.7]O-[:65,.7]?[b](-[2,.7]CH_2OH)<[:-60,.707](-[6,.5]OH)
      -[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[2,.5,,2]HO)>[:60,.707](-[6,.5]CH_2OH)-[:162,.9]O?[b])
  -[3,.7]O-[4]?(-[2,.3]-[3,.5]HO)}

\setatomsep{2em}
\chemfig{
  H_3C-[:72]{\color{blue}N}
    *5(-
      *6(-(={\color{red}O})-{\color{blue}N}(-CH_3)-(={\color{red}O})-{\color{blue}N}(-CH_3)-=)
    --{\color{blue}N}=-)}

\end{document}
```

[image: chemfig demo]

An `ochem` example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ochem}
\begin{document}

\begin{chemistry}
  set("rLenN",20)
  formula(L,R)
    {
      ring(,,H1=)
        {
          0: bond(r,=C) atom("O") ;
          3: atom("N") bond(r) atom("C",C,R) atom("H$_3$",L) ;
          4: bond(r,=C) atom("O") ;
          5: atom("N") bond(r) atom("CH$_3$",L) ;
          vertex(,1,4,H2=,5)
            {
              1: atom("N") bond(r) atom("C",C,L) atom("H$_3$",R) ;
              3: atom("N") ;
            } ;
        }
    }
\end{chemistry}

\end{document}
```

[image: ochem demo]

A `streetex` example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stree}
\begin{document}

\sffamily
\stree{0[2N[0{CH$_3$}]4[=2O]6N[4{CH$_3$}]8[=6O]10]/10N=75N[/7{H$_3$C}]/2}

\end{document}
```

[image: streetex demo]

A `XyMTeX` example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtex}
\let\substfont\sffamily
\begin{document}

\sixheterovi[{f\fivefusev[d]{1==N;4==N}{1S==CH$_3$}{b}}e]
  {2==N;4==N}
  {1D==O;3D==O;4S==CH$_3$}

\end{document}
```

[image: XyMTeX demo]

A `PPCHTeX` example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{m-pictex}
\usepackage{m-ch-en}% or `m-ch-de' if you like a German interface

\begin{document}

\startchemical
  \chemical[FIVE,FRONT,BB125,+SB3,-SB4,Z4][O]
  \chemical[FIVE,FRONT,+R1235,+RZ1235][H,H,\SR{HOH_2C},OH]
  \chemical[FIVE,FRONT,-R1235,-RZ1235][H,OH,H,H]
\stopchemical

\end{document}
```

[image: PPCHTeX demo]

Comment: xymtex looks (or looked) good, and the author published a pleasing paper in tugboat.  the author even uploaded to ctan ... once.  when i came to catalogue it, the home page had moved and the uploaded version had been declared obsolete.  the package is no doubt a boon for the author's students, but for those he chooses to keep in the dark, `chemfig` or one of the others i don't know seems the way to go.

Comment: The homepage seems to be http://homepage3.nifty.com/xymtex/fujitas3/xymtex/indexe.html nowadays. What I dislike most about `XyMTeX` is its documentation, actually. I find it very hard to deduce which commands are available (and what they do) and what options they have (and what they do). Otherwise it seems to be a very capable and complete bundle.

Comment: Totally agree as a 'jobbing' chemist: `chemfig` is the only one I'd actually use at all for 'real' work (although I personally do use a graphical tool for most of my work).

Comment: A convenient package, if you have SMILES on hand, is [chemobabel](https://github.com/aminophen/chemobabel). It permits embedding SMILES directly in the LaTeX. It relies on the `obabel` (Open Babel) executable.

Comment: in ```chemfig```, ```\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}``` is now: ```\setchemfig{cram width=2pt}
```

Comment: But sadly chemfig is [not available](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/554) on SE.

Answer (score 24):

For the purpose of rational comparison, 
more and updated information on XyMTeX would be desirable, 
because the example shown in the preceding answer has been 
drawn by the plain mode of XyMTeX (providing slightly poor 
printing quality within the picture enviroment of LaTeX) and 
because the comment on the availability of XyMTeX would 
provide readers with a misleading impression.

The latest version (Version 5.00a) of XyMTeX is available 
from the XyMTeX homepage (http://xymtex.com/):

http://xymtex.com/fujitas3/xymtex/indexe.html

The two structural formulas shown in the question can be 
drawn by using the PostScript-compatible mode (as well 
as the PDF-compatible mode) of XyMTeX.

(1) Disaccharide

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtexps}%PostScript Mode
%\usepackage{xymtexpdf}%PDF Mode
\begin{document}

\changeunitlength{0.08pt}
\utrigonal{0==O;2==%
\furanose{4==(yl);1Sa==CH$_{2}$OH;2Sb==\lmoiety{HO};%
2Sa==H;3Sb==H;3Sa==OH;4Sb==HOC\rlap{H$_{2}$}};%
3==\pyranose{1==(yl);2Sa==OH;3Sb==OH;4Sa==HO;5Sb==CH$_{2}$OH}}
\hskip4cm
\utrigonal{0==O;2==%
\fivesugarh{5==O;%
1s==\WedgeAsSubst(0,0)(-3,-5){120};%
4s==\WedgeAsSubst(0,0)(3,-5){120};%
3s==\PutBondLine(-15,0)(305,0){3.2pt}%
}{4==(yl);1Sa==CH$_{2}$OH;2Sb==\lmoiety{HO};2Sa==H;%
3Sb==H;3Sa==OH;4Sb==HOC\rlap{H$_{2}$}}[abc];%
3==\sixsugarh{6==O;1s==\WedgeAsSubst(0,0)(-3,-5){120};%
4s==\WedgeAsSubst(0,0)(3,-5){120};%
3s==\PutBondLine(-15,0)(305,0){3.2pt}%
}{1==(yl);2Sa==OH;3Sb==OH;4Sa==HO;5Sb==CH$_{2}$OH}[abc]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(2) Caffeine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtexps}%PostScript Mode
%\usepackage{xymtexpdf}%PDF Mode
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\changeunitlength{0.08pt}
\sixheterov[e{e\fivefusev[d]{1==\bluex{N};4==\bluex{N}}{1==CH$_{3}$}{b}}]
{1==\bluex{N};3==\bluex{N}}
{1==CH$_{3}$;3==CH$_{3}$;2D==\redx{O};4D==\redx{O}}
\\ \vskip0.5cm
{%
\let\substfont=\sffamily
\purinev[aj]{3==CH$_{3}$;%
4D==\addbscolor{\green}{\redx{O}};5==CH$_{3}$;%
6D==\addbscolor{\green}{\redx{O}};7==CH$_{3}$}
\quad
\def\grayx#1{\xymcolor{gray}{#1}}
\nonaheterov[aj]{1==\bluex{N};3==\bluex{N};5==\bluex{N};7==\bluex{N}}%
{3==\addbscolor{\red}{\grayx{CH$_{3}$}};%
4D==\addbscolor{\green}{\redx{O}};5==\addbscolor{\red}{\grayx{CH$_{3}$}};%
6D==\addbscolor{\green}{\redx{O}};7==\addbscolor{\red}{\grayx{CH$_{3}$}}}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For further information, please see XyMTeX-tips in the XyMTeX homepage 
(http://xymtex.com/):

http://xymtex.com/fujitas3/xymtex-tips/indexe.html

The present topic has been deposited as 130208a-ps.pdf, 130208b-ps.pdf etc.

As for a tool for publishing a book on organic chemistry, the combination of 
XyMTeX-LaTeX has been used to publish the following book:

S. Fujita, ["Organic Chemistry of Photography",](http://www.springer.com/chemistry/organic+chemistry/book/978-3-540-20988-1) Springer-Verlag (2004),

in which all of the structural formulas (among 480 illustrations) have been 
drawn by using XyMTeX.

Comment: Are you going to upload version 5 of XyMTeX on CTAN?

Comment: I am heavily engaged in writing another book on enumeration of 
organic compounds now (for a previous publication, cf. 
S. Fujita, "Symmetry and Combinatorial Enumeration in Chemistry", http://www.springer.com/chemistry/organic+chemistry/book/978-3-540-54126-4
Springer-Verlage 1991). And so, sorry to say that it is 
hard to support two WEB pages simultaneously.

Comment: @Fujita If the code is usable, I don't see why it can't go to CTAN: I send stuff there almost every week :-)

Comment: @Joseph Wright, Probably it is a psychological barrier for me to maintain two web sites with writing a book, although the code is usable.

Comment: @fujita: if you upload to ctan, all you need do is provide a short outline of changes (e.g., "this is v5.0, large number of changes since v4.xx").  we (ctan) look after the web page(s) for you, and provide searching tools specific to the subject matter; in short, we try to make life as easy as possible for the uploader.  mail `ctan@dante.de` if you have queries of detail.

Comment: @wasteofspace, Thanks. The deadline of the book I am now writing is 
the beginning of April. I hope to improve the documentation of XyMTeX 
after that deadline in order to meet the comment of cgnieder on 
the documentation. Would you please wait for a while.

Comment: @Fujita that sounds great. I always thought `XyMTeX` must be a very powerful package. What I'd like would be something like a command reference and a short section about argument syntax. I can see that this would be potentially a lot of work, though...