# How to install XyMTeX to work with TeX Live on Windows 7

Tags: installing, texlive, windows, xymtex

I write my reports with LaTeX. I use TeXmaker plus TeX Live distribution. I want to use XyMTeX in a document when I wanna use `\usepackage{xymtex}` but there are errors. I don't know anything about how to install a new package. I'm new to LaTeX but I'm well experienced with Windows

Comment: @Jasper ... except that xymtex isn't free (in the sense of "air", at least) so isn't in tex live.  xymtex is a marvel (and all that) but it's big and unwieldy and difficult to "keep up with"; there are real chemists around here (i was last a chemist in 1965...) -- they might be able to suggest something better.

Comment: I'll be grateful if someone suggests any other better package or bundle. Thank you jasper Loy.

Comment: I haven't used this package before, but I did look at it for some of my drawing http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig.  There is a brief tutorial/example at this location as well:  http://www.mychemistry.eu/2011/11/a-small-exercise/

Comment: Concerning alternatives have a look at [Can you make chemical structure diagrams in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52722/can-you-make-chemical-structure-diagrams-in-latex/53572#53572)

Answer (score 3):

For me, installing [XyMTeX](http://homepage3.nifty.com/xymtex/fujitas3/xymtex/indexe.html) worked well enough using the [`.zip` file](http://homepage3.nifty.com/xymtex/fujitas3/xymtex/xym500a/xym-up/xymtex500a.zip) containing the latest version. What I did:

- Download the [`.zip` file](http://homepage3.nifty.com/xymtex/fujitas3/xymtex/xym500a/xym-up/xymtex500a.zip)
- Extract it
- Copy the entire contents (`xymtex` folder) to my local TeX tree. On Windows with TeX Live, that is `%USERPROFILE%\texmf` (Linux `~/texmf`, Mac `~/Library/texmf`).

The `.zip` file contains the code plus source, but as it works without further unpacking I would just use as-is. Following the above steps, the simple demo

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtexpdf}
\usepackage{chmst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\Rtrigonal{0==C;1D==O;2==Cl;3==F}
\decalinevb{1D==O;2FB==C;2GA==H}
\end{document}
```

works fine using pdfLaTeX. (Note: the XyMTeX manual has `xymtxpdf` as the package name, but this seems to be erroneous as the file is called `xymtexpdf.sty`.)