# Drawing Kinetic Schemes in Latex

Tags: chemfig, mhchem

Do you think it would be possible to use the `mhchem` package and their arrows (e.g. `<=>>`) in drawing a cyclic kinetic scheme such as :
[image: Example cyclic kinetic scheme, sorry for my appalling drawing, that's why i use latex ^_^]

or do you think it would be better to use a different package?

Comment: The Chemfig package looks quite good

Comment: I don't think you *can* draw such schemes with `mhchem`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52722/can-you-make-chemical-structure-diagrams-in-latex/53572#53572 for some options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to draw such schemes with [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) but as **Twig** has already noticed [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) can be used. To expand a bit on **Twig**'s answer and `chemfig`'s possibilities: the `\arrow` command is the important macro here which is only valid between `\schemestart` and `\schemestop`. It has lots of arguments so here is a quick overview:

- draw an arrow and call the starting node `a` (before the arrow) and the ending node (after the arrow) `b`:

  ```
  \arrow(a--b)
  ```
- draw an arrow between previously called nodes `a` and `b`:

  ```
  \arrow(@a--@b)
  ```
- draw an arrow of type `<<->` (there a lots of others like `->`, `<=>`, `<->`, ... ) with text above and below:

  ```
  \arrow{<<->[above][below]}
  ```
- draw an arrow with angle `30` to the horizontal and with doubled length (whose default can be set for the document or the current scheme):

  ```
  \arrow[30,2]
  ```

These arguments can be combined. The following would draw an arrow of type `<=>` with “above” written on it and  1.5 times the default length with an angle of 30 degrees to the horizontal starting from node `a`, calling the node after it `b`:

```
\arrow(@a--b){<=>[above]}[30,1.5]
```

There's actually more but I believe this should suffice for a quick demonstration. The details are all explained in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/chemfig).

Now at last one possibility for the scheme shown in the question using most of the features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}

\schemestart
 Aa
 \arrow(A--B){<=>}
 Bbb
 \arrow{<<->[$10$]}[30] Eeeeee \arrow(--D){<<->[][$20$]}[-30] Ddddd
 \arrow(@B--C){<->>}[-30] Cccc
 \arrow(@C--@D){<->>}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer, the `chemfig` package is good:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
A \arrow{<=>} B \arrow[-45]  C \arrow[45] D \arrow[135] E \arrow[-135]
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

, however there is a problem with the double arrows on the square bit.

Edit:
Problem Solved

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\schemedebug{false}
\schemestart
    A \arrow{<=>} B
    \arrow{<->>}[-45]  C
    \arrow{<->>}[45] D 
    \arrow{<->>[\SI{20}{\Hz}]}[135] E 
    \arrow{<->>[][10]}[-135]
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The double arrows is because i can't read, its {<->>} not {<=>>}