# Chemical structures drawing: {table} vs \chemfig

Tags: tables, chemfig

I write a chemical structure as a table. Please help me understand, How can I reduce the distances between the rows and columns in a table? This is the structure of the zeolite and would like to make it look more compactly at vertical and horizontal axes.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\rm NH_4^+$} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\rm NH_4^+$} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
 & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  \\
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & Si &  &  &  &  &  & Al &  &  &  &  &  & Si &  &  &  &  &  & Al &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  &  \\
 & O &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  &  & O &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As such, your document is not complete, since `\diagdown` and `\diagup` are not defined

Comment: @EvgenyChem You have [chemfig](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf) in case it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do *not* use tables to draw chemical structures. There's the already mentioned `chemfig` package and a few alternatives available for drawing chemical structures and schemes, see [Can you make chemical structure diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52722#53572) and the posts tagged [chemfig](/questions/tagged/chemfig).

Also there's no need to use a `tikzpicture` for positioning the compounds. It's far easier to use invisible bonds by passing the TikZ setting `draw=none? to a bond's TikZ-Option (`[,,,,]`) and`chemfig`'s powerful scheme-mechansim.

The basic molecule here is easily drawn by creating a `O-Si-O-Al-O-Si-O` chain:

```
\chemfig{
  O-[:-30]
  Si-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  Al-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  Si-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  Al-[:30]
  O
}
```

The charges can be put above the `Al` atoms with `\chemabove`:

```
\chemfig{
  O-[:-30]
  Si-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  \chemabove{Al}{-}-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  Si-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  \chemabove{Al}{-}-[:30]
  O
}
```

Now we can add the side chains to the missing `O`s using `chemfig`'s `(...)` syntax:

```
\chemfig{
  O-[:-30]
  Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
  O
}
```

Last but not least let's draw invisible bonds from the `Al`s to the ammonium ions:

```
\chemfig{
  O-[:-30]
  Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)(-[2,,,,draw=none]NH_4^+)-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
  O-[:-30]
  \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)(-[2,,,,draw=none]NH_4^+)-[:30]
  O
}
```

The complete scheme as seen in [@EvgenyChem's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196648/) can then best be created using

```
\schemestart
  <compound>
  \arrow
  <compound>
\schemestop
```

In this case a vertical arrangement seems to make sense so we choose the default angle `-90` for the scheme with the optional argument of `\schemestart[-90]`. Here's an example for a possible complete scheme:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \small
  \schemestart[-90]
    \chemfig{
      O-[:-30]
      Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)(-[2,,,,draw=none]NH_4^+)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)(-[2,,,,draw=none]NH_4^+)-[:30]
      O
    }
    \arrow
    \chemfig{
      O-[:-30]
      Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)(-[2,,,,draw=none]H^+)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)(-[2,,,,draw=none]H^+)-[:30]
      O
    }
    \arrow
    \chemfig{
      O-[:-30]
      Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O(-[2]H)-[:-30,,,,draw=none]
      Al(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O(-[2]H)-[:-30,,,,draw=none]
      Al(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O
    }
    \arrow
    \chemfig{
      O-[:-30]
      Si(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      \chemabove{Al}{-}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O-[:-30]
      \chemabove{Si}{+}(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30,,,,draw=none]
      -[:-30,,,,draw=none]
      Al(-[:-120]O)(-[:-60]O)-[:30]
      O
    }
  \schemestop
  \caption{Caltination of zeolites} \label{fig:Caltination}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) instead of trying to accomplish your task with tables. It will give you the structure you need, and it's not too difficult to learn.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=300pt, paperheight=150pt]{geometry} % for this example only
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (-1.4,-1.5) (nh1) {%
\chemfig{NH_4^+}};

\node at (1.6,-1.5) (nh2) {%
\chemfig{NH_4^+}};

\node at (0,-3) (zeolite) {%
\chemfig{%
Si((-[:135]O)(-[:225]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Al((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Al((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:315]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result. You can specify bond angles and more.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is more professional, only that `chemfig` seems to load `tikz` automatically (because it is based on it).

Comment: @skpblack - thanks for pointing out the redundancy. I've removed the line to load `tikz`.

Comment: Thank you, @3cat. I just drew the structure of the Al-Si-structure and thought how to fix ammonium ions on the oxygen atoms. But without connection (-) it did not keep.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is to redefine the commands `\arraystretch` and `\tabcolsep` within the `table` environment.

`\tabcolsep` controls the spacing between before and after the column type specifier (`c`) in this case.
`\arraystretch` controls the spacing between rows.

You should use the values which suits your needs. My values were just initial guesses to show it works.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}




\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\rm NH_4^+$} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\rm NH_4^+$} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
 & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  \\
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & Si &  &  &  &  &  & Al &  &  &  &  &  & Si &  &  &  &  &  & Al &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  &  \\
 & O &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  &  & O &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\rm NH_4^+$} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\rm NH_4^+$} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
 & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  &  &  &  &  & O &  \\
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & Si &  &  &  &  &  & Al &  &  &  &  &  & Si &  &  &  &  &  & Al &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagup$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\diagdown$} &  &  \\
 & O &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{OO} &  &  &  &  & O &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Christian.
Now I will use a minimal working example.

Comment: *Please* don't promote this as a good idea! For chemical structures and schemes [there are dedicated packages available](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52722/can-you-make-chemical-structure-diagrams-in-latex/53572#53572) which are far better suited for the task.

Comment: @cgnieder: Of course there are better ways to draw such formulas, but the initial OP's request was about tables, not about `chemfig` etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't mind your answer (good that you undeleted it :) ). I'd just like to see a hint that it's better to look for an alternative since the “table“-approach will fail very soon for otherwise quite simple chemical structures

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. I upgrade the @cat3's code and that's what we have now:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\setchemrel{}{}{2em}
\small 
\noindent % Подавление красной строки
\chemfig{%
Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]{NH_4^+})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Si((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]{NH_4^+})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
}
\chemrel{-stealth}
\chemfig{%
Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]{H^+})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Si((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]{H^+})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
}
\chemrel{-stealth}

\vspace{\baselineskip} %Вставка пустой строки

\noindent % Подавление красной строки
\chemrel{-stealth}
\chemfig{%
Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90]H)(-[:315,,,,draw=none]Al((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Si((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90]H)(-[:315,,,,draw=none]Al((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
}
\chemrel{-stealth}
\chemfig{%
Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]\chemabove{Si}{\scriptstyle{+}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45,,,,draw=none]{}(-[:315,,,,draw=none]Al((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
}
\caption{Caltination of zeolites} \label{fig:Caltination}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to align this two lines to the left edge? I want shift the second line to left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
%\begin{center}
    \small % шрифт
    \schemestart
    \noindent
    \chemfig{%
        Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]{NH_4^+})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Si((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]{NH_4^+})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
    }
    \arrow{->[][][-15pt]}[,0.8]
    \chemfig{%
        Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]{H^+})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Si((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]{H^+})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
    }
    \arrow{->[][][-15pt]}[,0.8]
    \schemestop
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \schemestart
    \noindent
    \arrow{->[][][-15pt]}[,0.8]
    \chemfig{%
        Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90]H)(-[:315,,,,draw=none]Al((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]Si((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90]H)(-[:315,,,,draw=none]Al((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
    }
    \arrow{->[][][-15pt]}[,0.8]
    \chemfig{%
        Si((-[:135]O)(-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:90,1,1,,draw=none]\phantom{H})(-[:315]\chemabove{Al}{\scriptstyle{-}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O(-[:315]\chemabove{Si}{\scriptstyle{+}}((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45,,,,draw=none]{}(-[:315,,,,draw=none]Al((-[:240]O)(-[:300]O)(-[:45]O)))))))))))
    }
    \schemestop
    \caption{Text} \label{fig:Caltination}
%\end{center}
\end{figure}
\normalsize
```