# Simpler way to create chemical graphs using chemfig

Tags: chemfig

chemfig is a great package to draw molecules. But it's not very fast. I am searching for a software to create chemfig code of chemical graphs (molecules, reactions etc.). It would be great if it is free (better if it's open source :) ).

Comment: `chemdraw`? Your question could use some extra wording.

Comment: Sorry English is not my mother tongue. Chemdraw looks like a good software but it is very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a GUI tool that can generate `chemfig` figures. I usually use Marvin (free), export it to .svg then to .pdf and include it in a LaTeX document. You can use for example BKChem if you want something open source.