# Mhchem extension question involving chemical structure

Tags: mhchem, chemistry

Is it possible to typeset complex chemical structures such as the structure for carboxylic acid or aromatic compound using mhchem?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Can you make chemical structure diagrams in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52722)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out chemfig works really well for this.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? Perhaps "answer the original question". Otherwise this is better-suited as a comment.