# Cyclo-hexane Newman projection

Tags: diagrams, chemfig, chemistry, chemmacros

How can i draw this projection?

I'm already using chemfig, so i prefer a solution with it.

[image: cyclohexane]

edit: as requested, here is my mwe

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=newman}
\begin{document}
\newman{\ch{H},\ch{H},\ch{X},\ch{H},\ch{X},\ch{H}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you have so far? Please post a minimal example which provides people with a beginning and shows us where, specifically, you're stuck. Do-it-for-mes sometimes get answered - mostly if your question is sufficiently interesting or the image you want tickles somebody's fancy. But you are more likely to get useful answers if you don't rely entirely on the aesthetic preferences of our procrastination team coinciding with your diagrammatic needs.

Comment: I'm not posting a mwe cause i've just used the newman tool from the chemmacros package. See this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301894/drawing-chemical-structure-newman-projections

Comment: Why would that stop you posting an MWE?

Comment: Probably the best is to draw this from scratch with TikZ. `chemmacros`' `\newman` is rather limited in its possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found an answer [here](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7308/newman-projektion-mit-chemmacros)

Here is a quick solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\newman{H,H,,H,,H}\hspace*{-4pt}\newman{H,,H,H,H}
\bigskip
\newman{H,H,C\rlap{\ch{H2}},H,C\rlap{\ch{H2}},H}\hspace*{10pt}\newman{H,,H,H,H}
\end{document}
```

Here is a looooong solution with tikz (i'm going to study it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % die beiden Haupt-C-C-Achsen als Koordinaten definieren,
  % als Bindungslänge habe ich 1.5 ausgewählt:
  \coordinate (C1) at (0,0) ;
  \coordinate (C2) at ($cos(30)*(3,0)$) ; % benötigt `calc'-Bibliothek,
    % cos(30) ergibt sich aus einfacher Geometrie
  % Koordinaten in entsprechendem Abstand und Winkel von den Zentren definieren
  % und die vorderen Bindungen malen:
  \foreach \angle in {90,210,330}
    {
      \draw (C1) -- ++(\angle:1.5) coordinate (C1-\angle) ;
      \draw (C2) -- ++(\angle:1.5) coordinate (C2-\angle) ;
    }
  % die Kreise malen:
  \draw
    (C1) circle (.75)
    (C2) circle (.75) ;
  % die hinteren Bindungen malen und ebenfalls Koordinaten an deren Enden definieren:
  \foreach \angle in {30,150,270}
    {
      \draw (C1) ++(\angle:.75)--++(\angle:.75) coordinate (C1-\angle) ;
      \draw (C2) ++(\angle:.75)--++(\angle:.75) coordinate (C2-\angle) ;
    }
  % an den äußeren Bindungen H-Atome platzieren:
  \foreach \angle in {90,150,210,270}
    { \node[inner sep=0,anchor=180+\angle] at (C1-\angle) {H} ; }
  \foreach \angle in {30,90,270,330}
    { \node[inner sep=0,anchor=180+\angle] at (C2-\angle) {H} ; }
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (C1) at (0,0) ;
  \coordinate (C2) at ($cos(30)*(3,0)$) ;
  \foreach \angle in {90,210,330}
    {
      \draw (C1) -- ++(\angle:1.5) coordinate (C1-\angle) ;
      \draw (C2) -- ++(\angle:1.5) coordinate (C2-\angle) ;
    }
  \draw
    (C1) circle (.75)
    (C2) circle (.75) ;
  \foreach \angle in {85,205}
    { \draw (C1) ++(\angle:.75)--++(\angle:.75) coordinate (C1-\angle) ; }
  \foreach \angle in {95,335}
    { \draw (C2) ++(\angle:.75)--++(\angle:.75) coordinate (C2-\angle) ; }
  \path [name path=C1] (C1) --++(325:2) ;
  \path [name path=C2] (C2) --++(215:2) ;
  \draw [name intersections={of=C1 and C2}]
    (C1) ++(325:.75) -- (intersection-1)
    (C2) ++(215:.75) -- (intersection-1) ;
  \foreach \angle in {85,90,205,210}
    { \node[inner sep=0,anchor=180+\angle] at (C1-\angle) {H} ; }
  \foreach \angle in {90,95,330,335}
    { \node[inner sep=0,anchor=180+\angle] at (C2-\angle) {H} ; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```