# Is there any way to draw chemical structures using latex? Like , naphthalene?

Tags: chemfig

Draw some examples with napthol, phenol etc

Comment: You can look into `chemfig` package which has the potential to draw these kind of images. And, welcome to TeX.Se. Here, we don't prefer to entertain `do-it-for-me` class of question. Instead, we try to solve specific issues which you are encountering. Therefore, please try to do something with the packages to draw your figures and then if you must have a question, please post it here.

Comment: Related: [Can you make chemical structure diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52722/134144)