# Drawing a molecular structure using InChl

Tags: chemistry, structural-analysis

I want to draw adenosylB12 using its InChl formula:

```
InChI=1S/C62H90N13O14P.C10H12N5O3.Co/c1-29-20-39-40(21-30(29)2)75(28-70-39)57-52(84)53(41(27-76)87-57)89-90(85,86)88-31(3)26-69-49(83)18-19-59(8)37(22-46(66)80)56-62(11)61(10,25-48(68)82)36(14-17-45(65)79)51(74-62)33(5)55-60(9,24-47(67)81)34(12-15-43(63)77)38(71-55)23-42-58(6,7)35(13-16-44(64)78)50(72-42)32(4)54(59)73-56;1-4-6(16)7(17)10(18-4)15-3-14-5-8(11)12-2-13-9(5)15;/h20-21,23,28,31,34-37,41,52-53,56-57,76,84H,12-19,22,24-27H2,1-11H3,(H15,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,71,72,73,74,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,85,86);2-4,6-7,10,16-17H,1H2,(H2,11,12,13);/q;;+2/p-2/t31?,34?,35?,36?,37?,41-,52-,53-,56?,57+,59?,60?,61?,62?;4-,6-,7-,10-;/m11./s1
```

I wanted an output which looked similar to what is shown in the wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosylcobalamin

What packages or tools can I use to obtain this?

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52722/can-you-make-chemical-structure-diagrams-in-latex

Comment: Overleaf help is also available: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/chemistry_formulae