# Organic chemistry formulas

Tags: chemistry

I try to put this formula to LaTex:
[image]

but this code is not the best descicion for this problem:

```
{\left[{(-CF_2-CF_2-)}_n-CF_2-CF-\right]}_x
\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\overset\vert{(O-}CF_2-CF)_m-O-CF_2CF_2-SO_3^-M^+
\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\overset\vert{CF_3}
```

I also tried to find solution on this webpage https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chemistry_formulae
but I didn't find it((
Can you please help me

Comment: Please don't post code fragments, but instead put the fragment into a compilable document that includes `\documentclass{...}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. But as the Overleaf links show, there are various packages designed specifically for chemistry, so it would probably be best to try to use one of those packages to create your formula and then people can help you from there. Also the Overleaf documentation is *not* the full documentation for any of the packages it recommends.

Comment: To take up the space on the left, you can use `\phantom{...}`.  For line 2, just copy everything up to the "CF" in the first line, where the second line starts, but omitting the `\left` (which would cause an error) and one "(", to adjust for the one starting line 2.  For line 3, repeat the `\phantom` from line 2, then another `\phantom' starting with "(" and going on as far as necessary.  There are undoubtedly other solutions, but a simple hack seems easiest here.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.ctan.org/topic/chemistry . Chemstruct and streetex claim to handle otganic chemistry, though these two packages are quite old.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you make chemical structure diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52722/can-you-make-chemical-structure-diagrams-in-latex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\0{\vphantom{C}}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig[atom sep=2em, fixed length=true]{
        -[@{op2,-0.2},0.25,,,draw=none]\0-[@{op1,-0.2}]CF_2|\0-CF_2|\0-[@{cl1,1.2}]\hphantom{I}-CF_2|\0-CF(-[6]O-[@{op3,-0.8}]CF_2|\0-[@{cl3,2.2}]CF(-[6]CF_3)-[,0.5,,,draw=none]-O-CF_2CF_2|\0-SO_3^{-}M^+)-[@{cl2,1.2}]
    }
    \polymerdelim[height=2pt, depth = 4pt, indice=\!n]{op1}{cl1}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height=3pt, depth=5pt, indice=\!x]{op2}{cl2}
    \polymerdelim[height=2pt, depth = 4pt, indice=\!m]{op3}{cl3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\0{\vphantom{C}}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig[atom sep=2em, fixed length=true]{
        \0-[@{op2,-0.2},]CF(-[6]O-[@{op3,-0.8}]CF_2|\0-[@{cl3,2.2}]CF(-[6]CF_3)-[,0.5,,,draw=none]-O-CF_2CF_2|\0-SO_3^{-}M^+)-CF_2|\0-\hphantom{I}-[@{op1,-0.2}]CF_2|\0-CF_2|\0-[@{cl1,1.2}]\hphantom{I}-[@{cl2,1.2},0.3,,,draw=none]
    }
    \polymerdelim[height=2pt, depth = 4pt, indice=\!n]{op1}{cl1}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height=3pt, depth=5pt, indice=\!x]{op2}{cl2}
    \polymerdelim[height=2pt, depth = 4pt, indice=\!m]{op3}{cl3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for help. but my formula does not fit the width of the page. How could this be corrected?

Comment: @catauggie see edit

Comment: thanks for edit. I am  new in organic chemistry, but as I understand correctly, is it ok to reduce formula like you did in edit and it doesn't change it's meaning

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package [chemfig](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) to draw any kind of molecule.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{\phantom{CH_2}-[@{op1,.75}]-[@{op2,.75}]CF_2-CF_2-[@{cl2,0.25}]CF_2-CF(-[6]@{op3,.75}O-CF_2-CF(-[6]CF_3)-[@{cl3,0.25}]O-CF_2CF_2-SO_3^{-}M^{+})-[@{cl1,.25}]}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 6pt, indice = x, open xshift=-5pt, close xshift=-15pt]{op1}{cl1}
\polymerdelim[height = 4pt, indice = n]{op2}{cl2}
\polymerdelim[height = 4pt, indice = m, open xshift=-10pt]{op3}{cl3}

\end{document}
```

[image]